# how two website share same category and subcategory in magento

Tags: php, magento

i have created a addom domain(website) on a primary domai now i want to my addon domai share all the category and subcategory in magento 1.4 please any body tell me or provide some link which help me to solve this problem..how both domain share same products category..thanks..

Comment: It sounds like you have separate instances of Magento, each with their own database, is that correct?

Comment: No i have single magento installed in my primary domain.now i would like to know how another domain (Addon domain) share the category and product with their own theme.. thanks help will be greatfull..

Answer (score 1):

Here's step-by-step instructions to do what you want:
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/#subdomain-method

Comment: Also, I noticed that you have several question out there that seem to have been answered but haven't been accepted. If you get a a satisfactory answer to your question you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's ok to reply to this old post.. I followed the crucialhost tutorial (which is great by the way) and I've set up the second website as a subdirectory, however when I try to accesss the front-end the images & css paths are broken (note that I'm running wamp 2.1 on windows 7 and I'm using magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: @Bogdan: You should create a new question, and you can link to this post from there if you want.  A lot more people will see your question that way and you'll have a better chance of getting it answered.